# document.body evaluates to null

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Whenever I try to use `document.body.appendChild`, it evaluates to `null`. Here is my code:

```js
document.body.appendChild(c92w46);
```

I get this error:

```
main.js:96 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null
```

Comment: Your script is executed in the head section while the page is parsed, at that time `document.body` doesn't exist.

Comment: @Teemu So would `winow.onload` be a solution?

Comment: Yes, that's one of the many possible solutions, `DOMContentLoaded` event is another, `defer` or `async` attribute in the script tag (requires `src` too), or adding the script at the bottom of `body`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably it is trying to reach body before DOM is ready. You should use `DOMContentLoaded` event for DOM manipulation.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    document.body.appendChild(<element>);
});
```

Otherwise, it is better to share more code.